# Making my XNA sprite jump properly

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I have been having great trouble getting my sprite to jump. So far I have a section of code which with a single tap of "W" will send the sprite in a constant velocity upwards. I need to be able to make my sprite come back down to the ground a certain time or height after begining the jump. There is also a constant pull of velocity 2 on the sprite to simulate some kind of gravity.

```
// Walking = true when there is collision detected between the sprite and ground

if (Walking == true)
    if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            Jumping = true;
        }

if (Jumping == true)
    {
        spritePosition.Y -= 10;
    }
```

Any ideas and help would be appreciated but I'd prefer a modified version of my code posted if at all possible.

Comment: How does your constant velocity of 2 come into play?

Comment: Well, it's probably not the best way of doing it but it just makes the sprite travel downward all the time unless it's colliding with soething beneath it :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public class Player
    {
      private Vector2 Velocity, Position;
      private bool is_jumping; 
      private const float LandPosition = 500f; 

      public Player(Vector2 Position)
      {
         this.Position = new Vector2(Position.X, LandPosition); 
         Velocity = Vector2.Zero;
         is_jumping = false; 
      }
      public void UpdatePlayer(Gametime gametime, KeyboardState keystate, KeyboardState previousKeyBoardState)
      {
       if (!is_jumping)
         if (keystate.isKeyDown(Keys.Space) && previousKeyBoardState.isKeyUp(Keys.Space))
          do_jump(10f); 
       else
       {
        Velocity.Y++; 
        if (Position.Y >= LandPosition)
           is_jumping = false; 
       } 
       Position += Velocity; 

     }

     private void do_jump(float speed)
     {
            is_jumping = true; 
            Velocity = new Vector2(Velocity.X, -speed); 
     }
   }
```

fun little mix of psuedocode and some real code, just add the variables that I didn't include at the top.

Also check out Stack Overflow Physics ;) Good luck with your game.

edit: that should be complete, let me know how things go.

Comment: Thanks :] I definitely will, I could do with all the help I can :D

Comment: You're right about that other tutorial, I thought it was working right but it just sends the sprite to a predetermined height no matter where it's jumping from :/

Comment: try implementing my method, i'll edit it so that it's complete, give me a second.

Comment: So, I make this as a seperate class and not a method within my main class?

Comment: Yah, you're going to want to make any object that can be expanded upon into a class. A class is just a collection of variables and functions that have a purpose under one entity (a player can jump, it has a velocity, a position, ect.). All of these things make sense under the context of the "Player" so you group them into a class. It goes a lot deeper than that though, it sounds like you're just learning (which is great, I loved those days :) ) learn some more about the C# language, then about Object oriented programming (which is what I was describing) then come back to XNA. You'll understand

Comment: I find the best way to learn is by looking at code and seeing how things work in practice, I should be able to impliment this into what I have so far, it may just take a while :]

Comment: That's the best attitude to have. Patience, persistence, and drive will get you far in this industry, and again good luck.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the niceness of people on this site never ceases to amaze and delight me :]

Comment: Okay, well I understand to code now, and have it typed in. Now to trying to tie it in with the rest of my code :]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20583/discussion-between-matthew-morgan-and-josh-siegl)

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply an impulse to your sprite as opposed to a constant velocity of 10 like you are doing. 
There is a good tutorial [here](http://flatformer.blogspot.ie/2010/02/making-character-jump-in-xnac-basic.html) for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for sending that tutorial my way, It worked great

Comment: That tutorial's a little basic, check out my example. Remember it's always better to use functions so that later down the road you can add things to the jump, possibly override it (which can be used for multiplayer) ect.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this...

```
const float jumpHeight = 60F; //arbitrary jump height, change this as needed
const float jumpHeightChangePerFrame = 10F; //again, change this as desired
const float gravity = 2F;
float jumpCeiling;
bool jumping = false;

if (Walking == true)
{
    if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    {
        jumping = true;
        jumpCeiling = (spritePosition - jumpHeight);
    }
}

if (jumping == true)
{
    spritePosition -= jumpHeightChangePerFrame;
}

//constant gravity of 2 when in the air
if (Walking == false)
{
    spritePosition += gravity;
}

if (spritePosition < jumpCeiling)
{
    spritePosition = jumpCeiling; //we don't want the jump to go any further than the maximum jump height
    jumping = false; //once they have reached the jump height we want to stop them going up and let gravity take over
}
```

Comment: Although the example in that tutorial is way better.